# Why was my topic deleted from documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

I had earlier posted a topic on docs about constructing loops. There was general help in finding initial condition, iterative construct, and termination condition along with one example. It was approved by [Alex Filtov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173016/alex-filatov) on Aug 31. When I thought about referencing it again for some reason in docs, it was gone. Here is the [approval link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/91010). This will also give you the topic and its contents.

Can somebody tell me why it was deleted? I am not saying it was wrong to do, just an explanation. It will help me to improve myself. If it was a right deletion, then what was my fault? If it was a wrong deletion, then why did it happened?

Comment: You can see the comment for the improvement request that led to deletion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94324?filter-tags=algorithm).

Comment: I don't see how it is trivial. Beginners often struggle to understand the material on constructing loops. I know several friends who have. This will surely help in making it easier to construct loops. I understand this is trivial for experienced programmers but for beginners, I don't think this is completely trivial.